# Angular 9 application not working when using the --production flag

Tags: angular

my code works fine when using it in my test and development kit nodejs-angular9-npm but when trying to upload in production it fails after logging with the error.

```
main-es2015.383aaa42b125fc344b09.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: de.Subject is not a constructor
TypeError: de.Subject is not a constructor
    at new e (9-es2015.6c1279e40cf49ad37ce0.js:1)
    at Ce.e.ɵfac [as factory] (9-es2015.6c1279e40cf49ad37ce0.js:1)
    at tn (main-es2015.383aaa42b125fc344b09.js:1)
    at Ze (main-es2015.383aaa42b125fc344b09.js:1)
    at Ke (main-es2015.383aaa42b125fc344b09.js:1)
    at Object.Qs (main-es2015.383aaa42b125fc344b09.js:1)
    at Ce.he.h.forChild.component.e.ɵfac [as factory] (9-es2015.6c1279e40cf49ad37ce0.js:1)
    at tn (main-es2015.383aaa42b125fc344b09.js:1)
    at main-es2015.383aaa42b125fc344b09.js:1
    at main-es2015.383aaa42b125fc344b09.js:1
    at _ (polyfills-es2015.87ba1471bd6139208429.js:1)
    at _ (polyfills-es2015.87ba1471bd6139208429.js:1)
    at polyfills-es2015.87ba1471bd6139208429.js:1
    at u.invokeTask (polyfills-es2015.87ba1471bd6139208429.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main-es2015.383aaa42b125fc344b09.js:1)
    at u.invokeTask (polyfills-es2015.87ba1471bd6139208429.js:1)
    at s.runTask (polyfills-es2015.87ba1471bd6139208429.js:1)
    at k (polyfills-es2015.87ba1471bd6139208429.js:1)
```

The question here is why? what is the difference between dev and prod?

Again what works:
package.json

```
scripts": {
   "ng": "ng",
   "start": "ng serve",
   "build": "ng build --prod && nodemon server.js",
   "test": "ng test",
   "lint": "ng lint",
   "e2e": "ng e2e"
}
```

what does not work:

```
    scripts": {
       "ng": "ng",
       "start": "ng serve",
       "build": "ng build && nodemon server.js",
       "test": "ng test",
       "lint": "ng lint",
       "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
```

any ideas what to start looking for?

Comment: Do you want to build the application?

Comment: I am not sure about the question, can I load the application without the ng build part?

Comment: When does the error appear, when you build the project or when you start the application in production?

Comment: the application builds and starts okay and I can go to the login page, but once I fill the logging entries and hit enter the error appears and it does not continue

Comment: I assume you are working with rxjs subjects. Can you show the code where you are using it?

Comment: you mean:import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'; I have probably 10-15 services using the observables but I don't understand what will be the difference between having an observable in dev and in prod...will they not behave the same?

Comment: Maybe you an import is not correct. I would suggest to exclude / comment out your components & services that use these Obeservables and test if it works without it. Then add one component after another.

Comment: removing the imports did not work